# How to set and test a variable in child template to modify a block in parent template

Tags: scope

I would like to load some javascript on specific pages only.

I'm trying to set a block in my parent template, then test a variable and include the javascript in the child template only when necessary.

**I thought I could do this by declaring the variable beforehand, to make it  accessible outside it's scope**, but this is not working (nothing is returned):

Parent '_layout' template:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>

        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}

        ...

        {# site-wide script #}
        <script src="global.js"></script>

        {# page-specific script #}
        {% block script %}
        {% endblock %}

    </body>
</html>
```

Child template:

```
{% extends "_layout" %}

{% set page_assets = '' %}

{% block content %}
...
{% set page_assets = 'true' %}
...
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    {% if page_assets is defined and page_assets is not empty %}
      <script src="page-specific.js"></script>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that's not going to work unfortunately, due to the way scoping works in Twig. Check out the explanation in the [Twig Processing Order & Scope](https://nystudio107.com/blog/twig-processing-order-and-scope) article